# from llama_index import Document

Tags: pydantic, large-language-model, llama-index

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 4>()
2 from llama_index import Document
3 text_list = [text1]
----> 4 documents = [ Document(t) for t in text_list ]
5

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pydantic/main.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so in pydantic.main.BaseModel.**init**()

TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 4>()
2 from llama_index import Document
3 text_list = [text]
4 documents = [ Document(t) for t in text_list ]
5

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pydantic/main.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so in pydantic.main.BaseModel.**init**()

TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)